# Mercurial: merging with an external directory

Tags: mercurial, merge, branching-and-merging

I have a local repository, which I need to merge with a version edited the old fashioned way. I'd like to know what is the more straightforward way to handle this situation.

Apparently `hg merge` merges two *branches*, which are both *in* the repository. Am I supposed to create a new branch, copy the external directory in the repository, add it, commit, then merge? Is there an extension which just handles that? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other code was not under version control. Then you will need to merge it manually.

You can create another branch for this merge, but if all you are going to do is merge that branch into the main one. You should just merge into the main branch directly.